# Reading emails from Exchange online in c#.net using Office 365 API

Tags: office365api

I am trying to read emails from Exchange online through a Office 365 API.with using my username and password for authentication.

Is it possible to access the O365 api? (only using user credentials)

How can I do that? Anyone can help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your exchange online is part of Office 365, you should definitively take a look here : http://dev.office.com

You will find many tutorials to get access to your mails.
Take a look here : http://dev.office.com/getting-started/office365apis

It uses the Microsoft Graph to query your mailbox and retrives messages :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages
```

The authentication process is provided byt Azure Active Directory, through ADAL SDK.

In Visual Studio, you can create easily an application, and then call the submenu 'Add connected services' and you're done !

Comment: Hi Sir,Thanks to give me this approach but sir is it possible to access directly through oauth2 without using Graph?

Comment: Take a look at https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted for instructions as you can use Outlook APIs for mail with OAuth 2.  Just curious why you don't want to go through Microsoft Graph - can you please explain?  Once I know my answer is useful for you, I will post it as an answer, and not a comment.

Comment: Hi Sir,No any issue sir your answer is also right but future purpose i want best approach because there some difference between both of them... (i.e Some features may be available on the individual service endpoints (OAuth 2), but not yet on Microsoft Graph) Please refer this link " http://dev.office.com/chooseapiendpoint "